# Encoding/decoding troubleshooting for python CSVs and JSON files

Tags: python, csv, encoding, decode, utf

I initially dumped a file which contained a particular sentence using:

```
 with open(labelFile, "wb") as out:
        json.dump(result, out,indent=4)
```

This sentence within the JSON looks like:

```
"-LSB- 97 -RSB- However , the influx of immigrants from mainland China , approximating NUMBER_SLOT per year , is a significant contributor to its population growth \u00c3 cents \u00c2 $ \u00c2 `` a daily quota of 150 Mainland Chinese with family ties in LOCATION_SLOT are granted a `` one way permit '' .",
```

I then proceeded to load this in via:

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as sentenceFile:
    sentenceFile = json.loads(sentenceFile.read())
```

process it and then write this out to a CSV using:

```
with open(sys.argv[2], 'wb') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['x','y','z'
                  ]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for sentence in sentence2locations2values:
         sentence = unicode(sentence['parsedSentence']).encode("utf-8")
         writer.writerow({'x': sentence})
```

Which made the sentence in the CSV file opened in Excel for Mac:

```
-LSB- 97 -RSB- However , the influx of immigrants from mainland China , approximating NUMBER_SLOT per year , is a significant contributor to its population growth Ãƒ cents Ã‚ $ Ã‚ `` a daily quota of 150 Mainland Chinese with family ties in LOCATION_SLOT are granted a `` one way permit '' .
```

I then proceeded to take this from Excel for Macs to Google Sheets, where it is:

```
-LSB- 97 -RSB- However , the influx of immigrants from mainland China , approximating NUMBER_SLOT per year , is a significant contributor to its population growth Ã cents Â $ Â `` a daily quota of 150 Mainland Chinese with family ties in LOCATION_SLOT are granted a `` one way permit '' .
```

Note, very slightly different, the `Â` has replaced the `Ã`.

and then labelled it, bringing it back into Excel for Mac at which point it became back to:

```
-LSB- 97 -RSB- However , the influx of immigrants from mainland China , approximating NUMBER_SLOT per year , is a significant contributor to its population growth Ã cents Â $ Â `` a daily quota of 150 Mainland Chinese with family ties in LOCATION_SLOT are granted a `` one way permit '' .
```

**How do I initially read in the CSV, containing a sentence like**:

```
-LSB- 97 -RSB- However , the influx of immigrants from mainland China , approximating NUMBER_SLOT per year , is a significant contributor to its population growth Ãƒ cents Ã‚ $ Ã‚ `` a daily quota of 150 Mainland Chinese with family ties in LOCATION_SLOT are granted a `` one way permit '' .
```

**to a value which is:**

```
"-LSB- 97 -RSB- However , the influx of immigrants from mainland China , approximating 45,000 per year , is a significant contributor to its population growth \u00c3 cents \u00c2 $ \u00c2 `` a daily quota of 150 Mainland Chinese with family ties in Hong Kong are granted a `` one way permit '' .",
```

So that it matches what was in the original json dump right at the start of this question?

**EDIT**

I check from this and see that the encoding of `\u00c3` to `Ã`, the format in Google sheets, is actually Latin 8.

**EDIT**

I ran `enca` and see that the original dumped file is in 7bit ASCII characters, and my CSV is in unicode. So I need to load in as unicode and convert to 7bit ASCII?

Comment: reading it as a normal file instead of using CSV classes should do the trick

Comment: Can you post a solution or example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution to this. The solution was to decode the CSV file from its original format (identified as `UTF-8`) and then the sentence becomes the original one. So:

```
csvfile = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')

fieldnames = ("x","y","z")
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames)
next(reader)

for i,row in enumerate(reader):
    row['x'] = row['x'].decode("utf-8")
```

The very strange thing that happened is that when I edited the CSV file in Excel for Mac and saved, every time it seems to convert to a different encoding. I warn other users about this as it is a huge headache.